# Set "Related To" in Service Cloud Console Interaction Log

Tags: visualforce, javascript, service-cloud-console

Usually within the service cloud console, the "Related To" field in the interaction log is automatically set to the opened record.

We have a VF page overriding the account view and edit pages and the "Related To" field is not getting set in those pages.

The input tag that seems to contain the record id is hidden and generated when the site is loaded:

```
<input type="hidden" id="ext-gen424" name="tsk3_4880c85339ef85f8e17c15b550538fb213e227ba166zaa08be799646c350_lkid" value="500g0000001HGmi">
```

In the overridden pages, the value is simply "000000000000000".
I have been unable to change it (and I doubt changing the value is of much use once the page is fully loaded).

Any idea on how to pass the "Related To" value to the interaction log?

**Edit:**

the data is passed in JSON - the request url is:

https://instance.salesforce.com/ui/support/interaction/InteractionLogServlet?_dc=1366381704950&action=LOAD&newOptions=

Answer (score 1):

It sounds as though you need to keep track of what's called the "referrer page". You may need to create a custom controller in order to do this.

See [Defining Navigation Methods](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_quick_start_controller_navigation_methods.htm) for more information on the subject to see if this provides a solution to your question. It would at least allow you to keep track of the account Id as you move from page to page regardless of how you link between them. I'm confident there are other methods as well but this one is clearly a tried and tested method that's been proven to work.

Comment: Michael, if this provides a solution to your question, please let us know by marking your question as answered so others can benefit from the solution.:)